# Python pandas: banal apply statements incredibly slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numba

I have a pandas dataframe with ca. 250,000 rows. I am trying to create a new field as follows:

```
df['new_field'] = df.apply( lambda x: x.field2 if x.field1 > 0 else 0, axis =1 )
```

this works, but the single line above takes about 15 seconds to run!

I optimised it this way:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def mycalc(field1, field2, out):
    for i in xrange(field1.size):
        if field1[i] > 0:
            out[i] = field2[i]
        else:
            out[i] = 0

    return out

df['new_field'] = mycalc(df.field1.as_matrix(), df.field2.as_matrix(), np.zeros(df.field1.size) )
```

and it now takes 0.25 seconds.

My question is: is there a better way to do it?

The timing with the numba solution is fine, but the whole approach seems quirky: I would have hoped a calculation that banal could have been done efficiently in a single line. Plus, with numba in nopython mode, I need to initialise the output array outside of numba and pass it to numba, because I understand numba cannot create new arrays in nopython mode.

Some of the data comes from SQL, and the more I use pandas the more it seems to me I had better do in SQL as much as I can, because the speed difference is crazy. Now, of course I appreciate SQL will be faster when working on GBs of data, but 15 seconds for that banal calculation on 250k rows seens excessive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['new_field'] = np.where(df['field1'] > 0, df['field2'], 0)
```

So the above tests your boolean condition and returns `df['field2']` when `True` else it returns `0`

or in pandas style:

```
df['new_field'] = df['field2'].where(df['field1'] >0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! For more complex cases, where vectorising is harder if not impossible, would you recommend numba or something else?

Comment: Probably, always good to profile to see if something is worth doing